# best practice including javascript in django template

Tags: javascript, django, templates

Previously I used to do like this in a template

```
<html>
...
<script>
 {% include "myapp/includes/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" %}
{% include "myapp/includes/myscript.js" %}
</script>
...
```

But this causes all the js code to be shown on the page source.

I am not using any Form in my template, so can I use Media class for adding js?

Should I just use `<script src=".."`  or link ref=".." for adding javascript files? Which is the better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `<script src="yourscript.js"></script>` as usual, without the `include` template tag.

Django `include` template tag is not meant to load JavaScript source. It is used to include a *sub template* whose markup can access the template context of the *including template*. Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include).

Comment: And, while you're at it, start using django_compressor http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#examples

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is 6 years old, and the answer is an exact answer for the question. But somehow this came up for me so high in my google search results, I thought I would post additional info here, to help people like me, looking for best practice.  Use template inheritance, and blocks for content, css and javascript.

Docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance

and a stackoverflow example, showing how to add another js file to the original js block using block.super:

[how to organize JS files in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586259/how-to-organize-js-files-in-django)