# using django template logic in loaded JS files (integrate django JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, templates

I have a JS snippet that works and used in several files:

```
<script>
{% if not articles %}
    var url = {% url 'index:new-article' %};

    $('body').on('click',function(e){
        window.location = url
    });
    ;
{% endif %}

</script>
```

But if I put that code in a separate file 'main.js' and load it into the template, it will no longer work. It is now in 'main.js' as such:

```
var url = {% url 'index:new-article' %};

$('body').on('click',function(e){
    window.location = url
});
;
```

but when loaded like:

```
{% if not articles %}
    <script src="media/js/main.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```

in 'mytemplate.html', the code is now broken. Others advise simply including JS files you want to use into your django templates ([best practice including javascript in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162247/best-practice-including-javascript-in-django-template)). How can I use some template logic like my "if not this, include js file" and make it work? Thank you

Comment: @cody4321 what exactly do you mean by "the code is now broken"? Does it return an error?

Comment: clicking on the body element no longer opened a window. I went into the Chrome JS console and didn't see any errors. What are the tools you use to see errors? I never know why the JS is breaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% url 'index:new-article' %}` will return the raw string, you have to quote its output for it to be valid Javascript.

```
<script>
{% if not articles %}
    var url = '{% url 'index:new-article' %}';

    $('body').on('click',function(e){
        window.location = url
    });
    ;
{% endif %}

</script>
```

Comment: thanks Frank I'll check if that was the only issue soon