# how to organize JS files in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I am currently working with a Django project, I include different libraries JS and I create JS files for manage the other libraries, but I don't know the correct organization of JS files for each html page, for example, I have a "Main.js" and "Milk.js" in base template but I don't want have both files in the same base template, I want separate files for each page..

I tried adding as a normal js file

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/milk.js"></script>
```

But it  show me a error message  asking me several dependencies when inherited from base.html

I hope your help

**EDITED:**

Cuando he añadido en mis archivos de plantillas, sin mostrarme error en la consola de cromo pero en la consola django mostrarme los archivos JS de carga con 304 error.
[image]

The libraries are in base.html

it's strange, I can load milk.js when I click from home.html but when I will click in other page for example "cow.html" from "Milk.html" no load js file even when I did the same as "milk.html".

Comment: Can you show error details?

Comment: @mhassan I use JQuery JS but I include JQuery file in base.html, the error is missing of JQuery file.

Comment: are you including your base template in every template?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Django template engine has already provided a tag for inherit your HTML structure called 'extend'.

> Tag ***"extends"*** is a using for extends a parent template.
>
> {% extends "base.html" %} uses the literal value "base.html" as the name of the parent template to extend.

**base.html** is the parent template that can extendable.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
    <head><title>Hello World</title></head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>

        {% block scripts %}
        <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
        {% endblock %}
 
    </body>
</html>
```

and you have another HTML called **milk.html** that you need everything same as the base.html but include **milk.js** you just do something like this.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block scripts %}
    <!-- block.super will get the content of the block from the parent template -->
    {{ block.super }}
    <script src="{% static 'js/milk.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Read more about docs[1]: [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-extends

Comment: I also suggest to use {% load staticfiles %} and {% static 'main.js' %} instead of {{ STATIC_URL }} variable.

Comment: I have a simple doubt, it's need to add <head> in {% block content %} ?

Answer (score 4):

In your `base.html` file, add a block inside the `head` tag like this:

```
{% block scripts %}

<!-- some default content here -->

{% endblock %}
```

Now in your different templates files:

```
{% block scripts %}

<!-- insert per template scripts here -->

{% endblock %}
```

So in the templates with Milk, it would be like:

```
{% block scripts %}

<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/milk.js"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Being lazy, and extending the admin templates with `{% extends admin/base.html %}` I found that using `{% block scripts %}` did not work. The JavaScript was not sent to the browser. However `base.html` has a built-in block `{% block extrahead %}` which is empty and just the ticket for inserting additional content like scripts into the header.

```
{% block extrahead %}
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/milk.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```